# Are Supreme Leader Snoke and Kylo Ren Sith?

Tags: character, star-wars

As the general rule in *Star Wars*, all Sith will carry the title of "Darth", but Snoke and Ben never have such a title. Are they not Sith?

It is technically possible for someone simply turning to the dark side and not declaring himself/herself as a Sith, but the entire Star Wars plot line is based on the eternal conflict between Jedi and Sith.

It is not really logical for them to not be Sith.

Comment: Maybe they can come up with a new term like Jedi and Sith. ;)

Comment: @yeah, Disney can call them Donald and Mickey. :-D

Comment: You can note that there were no more Sith in the galaxy after Ep. VI. But it's canon now.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the entire plot line is based on Jedi vs. Sith, but more broadly on Good vs. Evil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, JJ Abrams & Andy Serkis confirmed that neither are Sith.

> "**Kylo Ren is not a Sith**. He works under Supreme Leader Snoke, who is a
>   powerful figure on the Dark Side of the Force." - JJ Abrams 
>   https://www.empireonline.com/movies/news/jj-abrams-spills-details-kylo-ren/
>
> Speaking with EMPIRE, The Last Jedi star said: “**He’s definitely not a
>   Sith**, but he’s certainly at the darker end of the Force. Without
>   giving too much away, that begins to unfold a little in this one." -
>   Andy Serkis
>   https://www.express.co.uk/entertainment/films/886261/Star-Wars-8-The-Last-Jedi-Snoke-sith-Andy-Serkis

Now there are not a lot of instances of dark-side force-sensative users whom are not Sith, although Asajj Ventress might fit the bill being a Jedi padawan turned assasin who just comes to work for the Sith, but there are light-sided ones such as Maz Kanata (New Trilogy), and an ancient Jedi splinter group: Ordu Aspectu (Doctor Aphra), but there is also The Bendu, a representation of the center of the Force (Rebels).

It makes sense that there can be the same thing for the Dark Side,--granted I'm not sure if *The Last Jedi* makes either Snoke's or Kylo Ren's "end game(s)" and overall philosophy perfectly clear, as much as it makes one question what everything is.

Comment: It is good to hear from a true Sith. :-)

Comment: So Snoke is not a Sith? Considering he's a Palpatine clone (an actual one, not just in the narrative) that's .... weird, right?

Comment: @BMWurm, while I would agree that the *current semantics on the matter allow for a gray area, one part of that gray area is that Snok(s) was influenced by Palpatine (via visual dictionary), but wasn't under his direct control, despite being made from his (and others?) DNA. So while it could ultimately be seen as a ruse, we still cannot fully discern how much of Snoke's beliefs were genuine to Snoke vs Sidious vs Sith Eternal. Between Mandoverse/TBB/and new books like Shadow of Sith, we may soon have better understanding, but at the time I answered this, what I wrote was the canonical answer.

Comment: I mean I even asked another Q if Palpatine is really 100% Palpatine for similar reasons, so I get where you are coming from, but as it stands, despite there is surely influence, Snoke wasn't say, possessed, and that allows that he/they believed they had some agency.

Comment: @DarthLocke I know, it wasn't a critique of your answer, more one of JJ most likely changing his mind when he unexpectedly returned for Episode IX - or maybe that was always the plan and nobody mentioned it to Andy - or Andy knew but of course couldn't say that before IX came out.      And I read that question of yours (which is incidentally how I found my way to this one :D)